# Incoming calls from unsaved numbers showing UNKNOWN NUMBER in my MOTO G

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I recently bought this phone for my dad and its upgraded to lollipop. But whenever any call is coming from an unsaved number, its showing "UNKNOWN NUMBER calling. " The phone happens to be brand new and i haven't yet added a google account or started using play store. Please help. Thank you for your kind attention.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when your phone contract doesn't include caller ID. When you have caller ID, numbers will show and Google will do a search to show you who is the caller.